# Sorting an array in c is deleting values

Tags: c, arrays, quicksort, genetic-algorithm, shellsort

I am programming a genetic algorithm so that this solves problems of linear programming, I am using C language, when I calculate the limit of the variables I keep the values ​​in a float type array, I need to order that array but it deletes a data that I need to moment of ordering: I have used a shell_sort pogramed by me and the qsort that is implemented in the standard librarian and with both gives me the same result, I append the code of the algorithm that I use to order and the comparator function that I use for the qsort () :

```
    void shell_sort(float *A, int n){
    int gap = n/2;  //Se obtiene el gap dividiendo el tamaño de arreglo entre dos
    int inner, outer, swap; //Variables auxiliares

    while (gap > 0) { //Mientras gap sea mayor que zero entonces:
        for(outer = gap; outer < n; outer++){ // Para outer igual a gap, siempre que outer sea menor a n, outer aumentara su valor en uno
            inner = outer; // inner se iguala al valor de outer
            swap = A[inner]; // Swap se iguala a la posiscion inner de A
            while (inner > gap - 1 && A[inner - gap] > swap ) {  // Mientras inner sea mayor que gap menos 1 y que A en su posicion inner menos gap sea mayor a Swap
                A[inner] = A[inner - gap]; //La posicion inner de A tomara como nuevo valor la posicion inner menos  gap de A
                inner -= gap; //inner decrementa su valor en gap veces
            }
            A[inner] = swap; //La posicion inner de A tomo como nuevo valor swap
        }
        gap /=2; // se divide a gap entre dos
    }
}
```

Comparer function:

```
int comp(const void * a, const void * b){
    if(*(float*)a < *(float*)b) return -1;
    if(*(float*)a == *(float*)b) return 0;
    if(*(float*)a > *(float*)b) return 1;
}
```

Output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua12V.jpg)
I think when I sort the array the result will be 0,26,37 but the result is 26,37 and I need that zero I don't really know why is this happen.

Hope someone can help me.

This is the piece of code when I use the sorting.

```
    Limites obtenerValoresLimites(lista *l,char var){
        //This code works
Limites lim;
        restriccion r;
        int i,j;
        float *aux = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
        for (i = 0; i < Size(l); i++)
        {
            r = Element(l,i+1);
            for (j = 0; j < strlen(r.variables); j++)
            {
                if(r.variables[j] == var){
                    aux[i] = (r.limite/r.coeficientes[j]);
                    }
            }
        }
    //First print of the output that confirms the zero originally exist

        //for (i = 0; i < sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux) ;i++)
            //printf("%f\n",aux[i]);

    //Sorting
        //qsort(aux,sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux)+1,sizeof(float),comp);
        shell_sort(aux,sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux));

        //printf("\n");
    //Second print of the output now the zero is no longer in the array
        //for (i = 0; i < sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux) ;i++)
        //{
        //  printf("%f\n",aux[i]);
        //}

        lim.inferior = 0;
        lim.superior = aux[(sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux))-1];
        lim.variable = var;

        return lim;
    }
```

Thanks for answer and read.

I think the code is a little bit difficult to read, its because we are using some data structures to modelete the problem so if you are interested in we leave the gitHub repo below.

Complete code if you are interesed in: https://github.com/JoelRomero97/Metodos-Cuantitativos.git

Comment: Time to [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you say that your sort and qsort of the standard library both return the same result, then I think the problem is somewhere else, perhaps you think you have a 0 in your array, or you are passing the incorrect size to both sort functions. Show us how you call the sort functions. Better still post a [mcve]

Comment: @Pable, either that or he is saying `qsort` is broken too...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, I know, but the likelihood that `qsort` is broken and not the OP's code, is very very small. It is not as if `qsort` was written yesterday by the friend of the maintainer of the the glibc (or any other well tested libc implementation). Funny note: when I was a beginner, I often though that I had found a bug in the libc, because some standard function didn't work as expected and it was always me who just used it incorrectly.

Comment: @Pablo In my school student from first year was yelling at me (I was a assistant) because `read()` was "bugged" ;) I still laugh when I see them even after 4 years. They keep saying that for 6 hours before finally understand the behavior of `read()` ;) The real fun was keep saying "read the man you miss a vital information". the bug was "read do not read n byte as I request but less" they was reading standard input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I suspected, the problem is in how you call the sorting function.

```
shell_sort(aux,sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux));
```

The `sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux)` construct works only for pure arrays, not for pointers (and also not for pointers that point to allocated memory).
When you allocate memory with `malloc` & friends, you know beforehand the size,
store it in a variable and use that variable for when you call the sorting
function or any other function that expects the size of the array.

Because `sizeof(aux)/sizeof(*aux)` is wrong, your are accessing memory beyond the limits, so this yields undefined behaviour.
And that is also true before you even call the sorting function. You are are
doing

```
aux[i] = (r.limite/r.coeficientes[j]);
```

for values of `i` larger than 1 (assuming that `Size(l)` is larger than 1).

You have to allocate the proper amount of memory, base on your code, I presume
you need `Size(l)` spaces. So the correct allocation should be

```
size_t len = Size(l);
float *aux = malloc(len * sizeof *aux);
if(aux == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
    return SOME_ERROR_VALUE;
}

for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    ...
}

shell_sort(aux, len);

...

lim.inferior = 0;
lim.superior = aux[len-1];
lim.variable = var;
```

Also, [don't cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: "pure arrays" XD

Comment: @Stargateur I use the word "pure" to emphasize that I mean `int arr[10]`. We often use the term array interchangeably when it comes to talking about contiguous blocks of memory allocations with `malloc`, and that's fine when you know the difference between an array and a pointer.